# Greg Egan does it again

Tags: discussion

Those who like reading this site will enjoy [his latest universe](http://www.gregegan.net/DICHRONAUTS/DICHRONAUTS.html).  E.g.

> Here, we sketch a possible world within this universe. We won’t call it a “planet”, because that word carries too much baggage from our own universe.

Although we *did* discuss [Multidimensional Time-Lines](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/35850) nearly a year ago, this set of [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) pages blows away anything that's been posted here.

Let’s raise a glass to toast **the** master worldbuilder.